# How do i execute two commands in cmd at a scheduled clock time?

Tags: windows, cmd

How do i execute these two commands in CMD at a scheduled clock time(as 10:53 PM)?

- CD desktop
- ffmpeg -i "https://X/index.m3u8" -rw_timeout 50000000 output.mp4

Comment: Assuming you are able to run `ffmpeg` line from cmd.exe, you can use Windows Scheduled Tasks to run that command like so: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FLacxP97MCA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, put all your commands in a single batch file.
Then, create a scheduled task for running it.

Type `SCHTASKS /Create /?` in command prompt for details about creating it.

At creation, you will probably want to specify either `/SC ONCE` for a one-time task, or `/SC DAILY` if you need it everyday.

Comment: Scheduler window save my life, thanks anyway for -indirectly- introducing me to it

Comment: @Themobisback Oh, I thought you wanted a solution to do it programmatically... If the scheduled tasks UI was enough for your need, fine, will be even easier!